# ErrorException: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 after changed to allow_url_fopen=1

Tags: php, laravel, svg, cpanel, ini

I got this error when appending SVG file to email-markdown file- in the laravel project.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents("../qrcodes/".$id.".svg")) }}" class="qrcode">
```

I add

```
allow_url_fopen=1
allow_url_include=1
```

in PHP INI editor.

and I still facing this error.

```
ErrorException: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

how can I solve it.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing php.ini

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, the project on shered hosting

Comment: Then ask your hoster's support, how you can actually change that setting - and _if_ you even can. Free hosting platforms often have features like this restricted.

Answer (score 1):

In shared hosting, php.ini values like `allow_url_fopen` are disabled server-wide for security reasons unless enabled by the root user itself. Even if you mention `allow_url_fopen=1` in shared hosting, it won't work. The alternative to this will be using `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents`.

Try this:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
?>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents_curl("../qrcodes/".$id.".svg")) }}" class="qrcode">
```

You can copy this function to your `functions.php` if PHP code is not meant to be pasted directly here.